# iPhone sdk read crash files programmatically?

Tags: iphone, crash, crash-reports, crash-log

I want to read crash files programmatically. 
How can I do this?

I am allowed to do this? Will my application be rejected if I do this?

Any advice, link, tutorial is well come.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure if its possible. You can’t access the logs themselves, but you can catch uncaught exceptions and generate your own crash logs for which I think you can make use of
the following example: http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/handling-unhandled-exceptions-and.html

it's very simple and easy to use, just register exception and signal handlers using:

```
NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&HandleException);
signal(SIGABRT, SignalHandler);
signal(SIGILL, SignalHandler);
signal(SIGSEGV, SignalHandler);
signal(SIGFPE, SignalHandler);
signal(SIGBUS, SignalHandler);
signal(SIGPIPE, SignalHandler);
```

and get the stack trace using the `backtrace` method in `UncaughtExceptionHandler` class.

Comment: The above link is broken, can anyone point to the appropriate reference

Comment: I believe the link is fixed as of now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible (at least on a non jailbroken iOS device). The crash files are written outside the application sandbox and they are transmitted to Apple by iTunes running on a desktop (if user allows it). So when you sync the iOS device with iTunes the crash reports are one of the items that are copied to iTunes.

A compliant App Store iOS application won't be able to read the directory that the crash files are located in.